# LongPath issue on WPF Drag Drop Getting Error: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: wpf-controls

In WPF, when I drag and drop a file with Long path that has more than 260 characters, it's throwing an error: `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`. Please let me know how to handle this. Is there any way to get invalid path and prompt for user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error HRESULT E\_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210405/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component)

Comment: None of them worked, this is related to LongPath issue